# Integrating Netbanking to website using JAVA/PHP (in India)

Tags: php, e-commerce, integration, onlinebanking

How to integrate netbanking feature to a website in JAVA/PHP technology?

Is there any common api available to integrate most of the banks to a website or else should we get a separate api for each bank that we wish to integrate?

Comment: *Integrate* the on-line interface of a bank? Whatever for?

Comment: Is it possible to integrate the online interface bank? Does banking websites provide access?

Comment: @user some do, but you usually need to be a big-name company to utilize such interfaces. What are you planning to do?

Answer (score 0):

IMHO there is no free api ..But you can use paid API of [CcAvenue](http://www.ccavenue.com)

But it is very costly. Other alternates like Google checkout & Paypal can be used for getting payments from Credit Cards